# xdebug with netbeans and wamp 3.0.6

Tags: php, xdebug

have WampServer Version 3.0.6 64bit 
so 
Apache 2.4.23 - PHP 5.6.25 - MySQL 5.7.14

I have downloaded php_xdebug-2.2.5-5.6-vc11-x86_64.dll and modified php.ini in this way:

```
[XDebug] 
zend_extension = "C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25\php_xdebug-2.2.5-5.6-vc11-x86_64.dll" 
xdebug.remote_port=9000 
xdebug.remote_enable = 1 
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp 
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\wamp64\tmp" 
xdebug.profiler_append = 0 
xdebug.profiler_enable = off 
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0 
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\wamp64\tmp" 
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s" 
xdebug.remote_autostart=1 
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0 
xdebug.remote_log=C:\wamp64\tmp\xdebug.log
```

But still Netbeans 8.02 doesn't stop on breakpoints.
phpinfo prompt xdebug.remote_enable = off

Why in your opinion?

Answer (score 0):

The xdebug entry in `php.ini` is relocated to `phpForApache.ini`. Open the file and  make `xdebug.remote_enable = on` .